# How does one express a vector in polar geometry in terms of Cartesian components?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, polar-coordinates

I have an expression for a magnetic field that I would like to express in (2D) polar coordinates as
$\mathbf{B} = B_\theta(r)\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$, where $B_\theta(r)$ is some known function of $r$.
However, I would like to express this vector in terms of its Cartesian components $B_x$ and $B_y$.

I know how to express ($x$, $y$) in terms of ($r$, $\theta$). However, I do not know how to convert the vector components. I read that for an arbitrary vector,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
F_x \\ F_y
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\ 
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
F_r \\ F_\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
However, it then seems that $F_x^2 + F_y^2 = F_r^2 + r^2 F_\theta^2 \neq F_r^2 + F_\theta^2$, so it seems like the transformation is changing the magnitude of the vector, which seems wrong.

What am I getting wrong about this problem? How do I express $B_\theta$ in terms of $B_x$ and $B_y$?

Comment: Vector coordinates in different basis might not have magnitudes given by the sum of the squares of their coordinates. It depends on what's chosen as basis vectors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_coordinates

Comment: Why a diff geo tag? This is linear algebra. Why do you think both bases are orthonormal?

Comment: "However, it seems that..." - No, this not a contradiction. The equation$$\begin{pmatrix} B_x \\ B_y \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\  \sin\theta & r\cos\theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B_r \\ B_\theta \end{pmatrix}$$you found is correct. Why do you expect the function$$\begin{align}A\colon\mathbb R\times\mathbb R&\to\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\\\begin{pmatrix}B_r\\B_\theta\end{pmatrix}&\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} B_x\\ B_y\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$ to be norm preserving?

Comment: It seems different people have different definitions of $\hat\theta.$ What is your definition?

Comment: @DavidK I see. The vector field $\hat{\theta}$ is probably normed so that the basis transformation is just a (norm preserving) rotation for each point.

Comment: In this case,$$\begin{pmatrix} B_x \\ B_y \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\  \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B_r \\ B_\theta \end{pmatrix}$$is the correct formula.

Comment: @mgmf46 There seem to be at least two possible answers to your question, and it really depends on how your vectors and their components are defined, $\hat\theta$ and $F_\theta$ in particular. One thing is for sure, you don't transform a unit vector to a unit vector with the matrix you used--as you already saw for yourself--so either you have taken a matrix from an incompatible set of definitions or you don't actually have two unit vectors. We cannot tell you what the problem is without more information about your definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're confusing [polar coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) / cartesian coordinates change, vs the change of coordinates in a rotated basis. In a rotated basis of angle $\theta$, the change of vector coordinates is just

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
F_x \\ F_y
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ 
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
F_r \\ F_\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$ and magnitudes are the same.